# Multiple Bottom Sheets not opening in react native Ios

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-ios

Hey folks I'm using `react native raw bottom sheet` in react native project.I'm showing a bottom sheet when the user click on an icon.It's working fine on both **android and ios**, when he selects an element from the bottom sheet I'm trying to close that sheet and **open a brand new sheet** with **subcategories** and its opening on android but not on ios, I don't know whats the issue on ios,kindly help me out to tackle this.
Here is my code

**Button to open first BottomSheet**

```
<TouchableOpacity
            style={{
              height: 27,
              width: 20,
            }}
            onPress={() => optionSheet.current.open()}>
            <Image
              source={more}
              style={{height: 17, width: 17, tintColor: 'black'}}
            />
          </TouchableOpacity>
```

**First BottomSheet**

```
<RBSheet
    ref={optionSheet}
    height={360}
    openDuration={250}
    customStyles={{
      container: {
        borderTopRightRadius: 30,
        borderTopLeftRadius: 30,
        paddingTop: 20,
      },
    }}>
    <TouchableOpacity
      onPress={() => {
        Snackbar.show({
          text: ' Saved to playlist',
          duration: Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG,
          action: {
            text: 'Change',
            textColor: 'tomato',
            onPress: () => {
              handleAction();
              optionSheet.current.close();
              playListRef.current.open();
            },
          },
        });
      }}
      style={[styles.horizontalContainer, {marginLeft: 4, padding: 10}]}>
     
      <Text
        style={[
          styles.large,
          {alignSelf: 'center', fontSize: 18, margin: 5},
        ]}>
        Save to playlist
      </Text>
    </TouchableOpacity>
   
  </RBSheet>
```

**Here is my 2nd sheet which will open when I will click on Snackbar action button**

```
    <RBSheet
    ref={playListRef}
    height={420}
    openDuration={250}
    customStyles={{
      container: {
        borderTopRightRadius: 30,
        borderTopLeftRadius: 30,
        paddingTop: 10,
      },
    }}>
    <TouchableOpacity
      onPress={() => {
        setBilal(!bilal);
      }}
      style={[styles.horizontalContainer, {marginLeft: 14, padding: 10}]}>
      <CheckBox
        center
        checked={bilal}
        checkedColor="red"
        onPress={() => {
          setNudity(!nudity);
        }}
        containerStyle={{padding: 0}}
      />
      <Text
        style={[
          styles.large,
          {alignSelf: 'center', fontSize: 18, margin: 5},
        ]}>
        Bilal
      </Text>
    </TouchableOpacity>
    <Divider style={styles.dividerStyle} />
    <TouchableOpacity
      onPress={() => {
        setmyFav(!myFav);
      }}
      style={[styles.horizontalContainer, {marginLeft: 14, padding: 10}]}>
      <CheckBox
        center
        checked={myFav}
        checkedColor="red"
        onPress={() => {
          setmyFav(!myFav);
        }}
        containerStyle={{padding: 0}}
      />
      <Text
        style={[
          styles.large,
          {alignSelf: 'center', fontSize: 18, margin: 5},
        ]}>
        My Favourites
      </Text>
    </TouchableOpacity>
    <Divider style={styles.dividerStyle} />
    <TouchableOpacity
      onPress={() => {
        setDaring(!daring);
      }}
      style={[styles.horizontalContainer, {marginLeft: 14, padding: 10}]}>
      <CheckBox
        center
        checked={daring}
        checkedColor="red"
        onPress={() => {
          setDaring(!daring);
        }}
        containerStyle={{padding: 0}}
      />
      <Text
        style={[
          styles.large,
          {alignSelf: 'center', fontSize: 18, margin: 5},
        ]}>
        Daring
      </Text>
    </TouchableOpacity>
    <Divider style={styles.dividerStyle} />
    <TouchableOpacity
      onPress={() => {
        setBest(!best);
      }}
      style={[styles.horizontalContainer, {marginLeft: 14, padding: 10}]}>
      <CheckBox
        center
        checked={best}
        checkedColor="red"
        onPress={() => {
          setBest(!best);
        }}
        containerStyle={{padding: 0}}
      />
      <Text
        style={[
          styles.large,
          {alignSelf: 'center', fontSize: 18, margin: 5},
        ]}>
        Best
      </Text>
    </TouchableOpacity>
    <Divider style={styles.dividerStyle} />
    <TouchableOpacity
      onPress={() => {
        Snackbar.show({
          text: 'New playlist added',
        });
      }}
      style={[styles.horizontalContainer, {marginLeft: 14, padding: 10}]}>
      <MaterialIcons
        name="playlist-add"
        size={23}
        color={'gray'}
        style={{alignSelf: 'center', margin: 5}}
      />
      <Text
        style={[
          styles.large,
          {alignSelf: 'center', fontSize: 18, margin: 5},
        ]}>
        Add new playlist
      </Text>
    </TouchableOpacity>
    <Divider style={styles.dividerStyle} />
    <TouchableOpacity
      style={styles.smallButton}
      onPress={() => {
        playListRef.current.close();
      }}>
      <Text
        style={[styles.largeText, {color: 'white', alignSelf: 'center'}]}>
        Save
      </Text>
    </TouchableOpacity>
  </RBSheet>
```

On clicking the **Change** button in Snackbar the 2nd bottom sheet is not opening on ios butt opening on the android,I am using **`useRef from React`**

Answer (score 2):

If you want to open another RBSheet then You must write the code of second RBsheet in the first RBSheet like

```
<RBSheet
ref={optionSheet}
height={360}
openDuration={250}
customStyles={{
  container: {
    borderTopRightRadius: 30,
    borderTopLeftRadius: 30,
    paddingTop: 20,
  },
}}>
<TouchableOpacity
  onPress={() => {
    Snackbar.show({
      text: ' Saved to playlist',
      duration: Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG,
      action: {
        text: 'Change',
        textColor: 'tomato',
        onPress: () => {
          playListRef.current.open();
        },
      },
    });
  }}
  style={[styles.horizontalContainer, {marginLeft: 4, padding: 10}]}>
 
  <Text
    style={[
      styles.large,
      {alignSelf: 'center', fontSize: 18, margin: 5},
    ]}>
    Save to playlist
  </Text>
</TouchableOpacity>

//Second RBsheet
    <RBSheet
    ref={playListRef}
    height={360}
    openDuration={250}
    customStyles={{
      container: {
        borderTopRightRadius: 30,
        borderTopLeftRadius: 30,
        paddingTop: 20,
      },
    }}>
         </RBSheet>
  </RBSheet>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is not currently possible on iOS for the react-native-raw-bottom-sheet library.  Take a look at this issue.

https://github.com/nysamnang/react-native-raw-bottom-sheet/issues/35

Comment: While this might answer the question, if possible you should [edit] your answer to include the most important and relevant information from the link provided in the answer itself. This helps to ensure your answer doesn't become invalid if the link stops working or the content significantly changes.